# Count of Records and Average of count of records Query - Oracle

Tags: oracle

Output like:

Year -> Month -> Product Name -> Total count of records for the year -> Average count of records for the year

My query returns the total and average for the whole year, I would like it to be broken down by month as well:

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID,PRODUCT_NAME,EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE), COUNT(ID) AS TOTAL_COUNT,COUNT(ID)/COUNT(DISTINCT(EXTRACT(DATE))) AS AVG_NO_RECORDS
FROM TABLE
GROUP  BY  PRODUCT_ID,PRODUCT_NAME,EXTRACT(YEAR  FROM DATE)
```

Comment: Hi RMS, welcome to SO. Please share your table structure, input records, and expected output.  Please check [These tips for asking SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that you used bunch of invalid things in this sample query (`table` is invalid table name, `date` is invalid column name, one of `extract`s is wrong), you'd use `TO_CHAR` on the date column with desired format mask - such as `mm` - and group by it as well. Something like this:

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID,
       PRODUCT_NAME,
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE), 
       -- 
       to_char(date, 'mm') as month,   --> this ...
       --
       COUNT(ID) AS TOTAL_COUNT,
       COUNT(ID)/COUNT(DISTINCT(EXTRACT(DATE))) AS AVG_NO_RECORDS
FROM TABLE
GROUP  BY  PRODUCT_ID,
           PRODUCT_NAME,
           EXTRACT(YEAR  FROM DATE),
           to_char(date, 'mm')         --> ... and this
```

On the other hand, if you're already grouping by year and month, see if you can use a single column for that, e.g. `to_char(date_column, 'mm.yyyy')`.